# PHP pick up post input text fields and post images in two arrays?

Tags: php, html, form-submit

im trying to pick up all of these fields, theyre all not required, just what ever is posted
storing one with vehicle info(this one is working)
storing second one with vehicle posted pictures (not working, dont know how)
then sending both arrays in a `add_car($vehicleinfo, &veihiclepictures)` function 
from there a file  `move_uploaded_file` will be called and actually put the file in the folder and the address in the mysql

can anyone help me achive this, im completly lost

```
    <div class="addacar">
        <h3>Add a Car</h3>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="one"><ul>

            <li>
                Year:<br>
                <input type="text" name="year">
            </li>
            <li>
                Make:<br>
                <input type="text" name="make">
            </li>
            <li>
                Model:<br>
                <input type="text" name="model">
            </li>
            <li>
                Engine:<br>
                <input type="text" name="engine">
            </li>
            <li>
                Sound System:<br>
                <input type="text" name="sound_system">
            </li>
            <li>
                Mileage:<br>
                <input type="text" name="mileage">
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
        <ul>
            <li>
                PRICE:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att1">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 2:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att2">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 3:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att3">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 4:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att4">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 5:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att5">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 6:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att6">
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
            <li>
                Attribute 7:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att7">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 8:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att8">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 9:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att9">
            </li>
                <li>
                Attribute 10:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att10">
            </li>
            <li>
                Attribute 11:<br>
                <input type="text" name="att11">
            </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
        <ul>
            <li>Picture 1<input type="file" name="picture"></li>
            <li>Picture 2<input type="file" name="picture2"></li>
            <li>Picture 3<input type="file" name="picture3"></li>
            <li>Picture 4<input type="file" name="picture4"></li>
            <li>Picture 5<input type="file" name="picture5"></li>
            <li>Picture 6<input type="file" name="picture6"></li>
            <li>Picture 7<input type="file" name="picture7"></li>
            <li>Picture 8<input type="file" name="picture8"></li>
            <li>Picture 9<input type="file" name="picture9"></li>
            <li>Picture10<input type="file" name="picture10"></li>
            <li>Picture11<input type="file" name="picture11"></li>
            <li>Picture12<input type="file" name="picture12"></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <li><input type="submit"></li>
    </form>
        <div id="clear"></div>






 <?php
    if (isset($_POST) === true && isset($_FILES) === true)
    {

                    $vehicleinfo = array
                    (
                    'year'          => $_POST['year'],
                    'make'          => $_POST['make'],
                    'model'         => $_POST['model'],
                    'engine'        => $_POST['engine'],
                    'sound_system'  => $_POST['sound_system'],
                    'mileage'       => $_POST['mileage'],
                    'att1'          => $_POST['att1'],
                    'att2'          => $_POST['att2'],
                    'att3'          => $_POST['att3'],
                    'att4'          => $_POST['att4'],
                    'att5'          => $_POST['att5'],
                    'att6'          => $_POST['att6'],
                    'att7'          => $_POST['att7'],
                    'att8'          => $_POST['att8'],
                    'att9'          => $_POST['att9'],
                    'att10'         => $_POST['att10'],
                    'att11'         => $_POST['att11'],
                    'att12'         => $_POST['att12']);
                    $vehiclepictures = array (
                    'picture1'          => $_FILES['picture1'],
                    'picture2'          => $_FILES['picture2'],
                    'picture3'          => $_FILES['picture3'],
                    'picture4'          => $_FILES['picture4'],
                    'picture5'          => $_FILES['picture5'],
                    'picture6'          => $_FILES['picture6'],
                    'picture7'          => $_FILES['picture7'],
                    'picture8'          => $_FILES['picture8'],
                    'picture9'          => $_FILES['picture9'],
                    'picture10'         => $_FILES['picture10'],
                    'picture11'         => $_FILES['picture11'],
                    'picture12'         => $_FILES['picture12']

                    );
                    //add_car($vehicleinfo);
                    //header('Location: admin.php?success');
                    //exit();
                    print_r($vehicleinfo);
                    print_r($vehiclepictures);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give your submit button a name like

```
<input name="submit" type="submit">
```

Then change

```
if (isset($_POST) === true && isset($_FILES) === true)
```

to

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
    // ...
}
```

Also notice, you have

```
'att12' => $_POST['att12']);
```

but you don't have a `12th` input, instead, your last `input` is

```
<input type="text" name="att11">
```

So, you should add another

```
<input type="text" name="att12">
```

Finally, I don't know what you are trying to do but it doesn't look good to me.